# Single term for "as a corollary"

Tags: word-choice

In academic writing, I often have to say something like "We found that the percentage of X questions increased by 10%, and as a corollary, the percentage of Y questions decreased by a similar amount."

How do I say "as a corollary" in a single term? To clarify what I'm trying to mean by that, other rough equivalent terms might be "consequently", "equivalently", etc.

Comment: You've answered your own question.  It's not clear what else you'd like to know, other than more synonyms for 'consequently' or 'equivalently.'

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the variables are related. Some possibilities.

"and thus, the number of Y..."

"and consequently, the number of Y..."

"and necessarily, the number of Y..."

"implying the number of Y..."

"resulting in the number of Y..."

"causing the number of Y..."

"forcing the number of Y..."

That's all I got!

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing a causative connection, and there are many words that do that. As you mention, "consequently" says exactly what you intend. Depending on how specific you need to be, you could also consider *Relatedly, Similarly, as a result, by extension, therefore...*

You may well have to back up your assertion that two things are related with further explanation, or proof that one is directly caused by the other. However, just expressing relatedness or causation with a word or phrase is relatively easy. Borrow (copy) phrases from similar academic writing!

Answer (score -1):

maybe 'Tangentially' - incidentally related. I have yet to get to use that one in casual conversation.